# Are both expressions evaluated when using ternary operator?

Tags: c

I was practicing some Leetcode problems and I ran into this unexpected runtime error. I'm doing some signed integer operations and trying to set my input negative (i.e. 5 => -5 and -8 => -8)

However, in the case of a INT_MIN input when using a ternary operator, I get an integer overflow. Using an if statement, I don't.

```
x = x < 0 ? x : x * -1;

>>> runtime error: negation of -2147483648 cannot be represented in type 'int'
```

vs.

```
if (x > 0)
    x *= -1;

>>> no problems with this one
```

Leetcode says "Compiled with gcc 8.2 using the gnu99 standard." for the language info. Is this expected behavior for all versions of C? My naive expectation was that a ternary operator was just syntactic sugar for normal control flow, but clearly I'm wrong on that

Comment: It should not be evaluated. It looks like a bug in a compiler

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No.  The spec requires that only one of the operands after the `?` is evaluated.  From 6.5.15 of the C99 spec:

> The first operand is evaluated; there is a sequence point after its evaluation. The second
> operand is evaluated only if the first compares unequal to 0; the third operand is evaluated
> only if the first compares equal to 0; the result is the value of the second or third operand
> (whichever is evaluated), converted to the type described below.  If an attempt is made
> to modify the result of a conditional operator or to access it after the next sequence point,
> the behavior is undefined.

Answer (score 1):

It's a compiler bug.

The error message is generated by the sanitizer enabled with `-fsanitize=undefined` flag. The sanitizer adds runtime checks that emit error message whenever *Undefined Behavior* is invoked. It looks that there was an error in older versions of this diagnostic look.

The other branch should not be evaluated as described in the other [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72421311/4989451). The issue was present till GCC 10.1 and it was fixed in GCC 10.2.

See https://godbolt.org/z/e5KWGsPfK

The list of bugfixes in this release is found at [bugdixes](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/buglist.cgi?bug_status=RESOLVED&resolution=FIXED&target_milestone=10.2). It's difficult to say which one is actual fix of the issue.